# How to show my customaized alert box over bootstrap3 modal box?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal with a form. When iam clicking on the save button, my jquery function will check the form element is empty or not. If it is empty, a customized error message will show.

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="Item-Modal" form-name="ItemMaster" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="heading"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="ItemADD">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputItemName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Item Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control enter modal-count" id="ItemName" value="" tabindex="1" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary modal-save" tabindex="2" id="btnsave">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

// jquery

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Item-Modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $("#btnsave").on('click', function () {
                    var value = $('#ItemName').val();
                    if (value == '') {
                        Simple.render1('Please enter a vehicle brand name!');// my custom alert box
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My problem is that alert box is appearing below of the modal box. What is the solution?(normal alert box is working...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself. It is a problem related on css.
Adding the following code on the displaying page

```
#div_id{
  z-index: 5000;
 }
```

where div_id is the div name of the alert box body......

Answer (score 0):

Add a div with the custom popup inside the modal and set it to hidden. Use a few more lines of js to display it whenever there's an event that requires the custom popup